# printing several tables onto a pdf using iText7

Tags: java, itext7

I am trying to fit several tables onto one page. I have implemented a potential solution, my problem is how to go to the next print area when I want to, rather that when the current print area is filled.
This is what it output looks like now. I have increased the font size so that the second area is partially filled automatically. Is there a way for me to tell it to use the next area when I want to rather than when iText7 wants to?

[image: The image shows 2 areas on a pdf page]

My code is:

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.itextpdf.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.layout.LayoutArea;
import com.itextpdf.layout.layout.LayoutResult;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.DocumentRenderer;

public class ColumnDocumentRendererTest {
    static PdfDocument pdfDoc;
    static Document document;
    Table tble;
    protected int nextAreaNumber = 0;

    public static final String DEST = "./target/test/resources/sandbox/tables/horizontzl_alignment.pdf";

    public ColumnDocumentRendererTest(Document document2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new ColumnDocumentRendererTest(document).createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    document = new Document(pdfDoc);
    ColumnDocumentRenderer renderer = new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document);
    document.setRenderer(renderer);

    //Add paragraph to the document
    tble = new Table(new float[] { 3f, 3f, 3f, 3f, 3f, 3f, 3f });
    /*tble.addCell(new Cell()
        .add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.nextToken()).setFont(font)));*/
    for (int i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {
        tble.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(Integer.toString(i))
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)
            .setFontSize((float) 20.5)));
    }

    document.add(tble);
    document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can ad an area break, but not inside a single table. It is assumed that a single table is to be rendered continuously, with each area containing add many rows as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't read the documentation for iText7, which provides a well-explained answer to this problem. (see [iText7 documentation](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2))

The answer proved to be to use "canvas" rather than "document".
The following code solves the use-case:

```
 public class TablePrinter {
    static PdfDocument pdfDoc;
    Table tble;
    protected int nextAreaNumber = 0;

    public TablePrinter() {

    }

    public static final String DEST = "./target/test/resources/sandbox/tables/tables_printed.pdf";

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, java.io.IOException {
    //
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
    PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_BOLD);

    pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.addNewPage();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(70, 722, 200, 100);
    pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
    pdfCanvas.stroke();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, rectangle);
    Text title = new Text("The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde")
        .setFont(bold);
    Text author = new Text("Robert Louis Stevenson").setFont(font);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add(title).add(" by ").add(author);
    canvas.add(p);

    rectangle = new Rectangle(310, 722, 200, 100);
    pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
    pdfCanvas.stroke();
    canvas.close();
    canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, rectangle);

    tble = new Table(new float[] { 3f, 3f, 3f, 3f, 3f, 3f, 3f });
    /*tble.addCell(new Cell()
        .add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.nextToken()).setFont(font)));*/

    int DaysInMonth = 31;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++) {
        if (i <= DaysInMonth) {
        tble.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(Integer.toString(i))
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)
            .setFontSize((float) 8.0)));
        if ((i >= DaysInMonth) && (i % 7 == 0))
            break;
        } else {
        tble.addCell(new Cell());
        if (i % 7 == 0)
            break;
        }
    }
    p = new Paragraph().add(tble);
    canvas.add(p);

    canvas.close();
    pdfDoc.close();
    //
    }

    public void addParagraph(Document document, int count) {
    Paragraph p;
    TextAlignment alignment;
    for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {
        p = new Paragraph("entry" + String.valueOf(i));
        alignment = (i % 2 != 0) ? TextAlignment.LEFT : TextAlignment.RIGHT;
        p.setTextAlignment(alignment);
        document.add(p);
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, java.io.IOException {

    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new TablePrinter().createPdf(DEST);
    }

}
```

Comment: Adding an `AreaBreak` could have worked too, as @mkl indicated in his comment. That's probably the easiest solution. Another solution could be to extend the `DocumentRenderer` as is done in the `MyColumnRenderer` class in [chapter 2](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2) of the tutorial. However, that's more complex to achieve than what you are doing in your answer, so +1 for the answer (and while I was at it, I gave you +1 for the question too).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: Your upvoting and kind comments are much appreciated.